# How can I access the result from a promise inside another?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am playing around with promises, I have the following code to access my mongodb:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(client => {
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    return db.collection('dogs');
  })
  .then(collection => collection.find().toArray())
  .then(array => console.log(array))
  // Client is not defined, how do I access it?
  .finally(() => client.close())
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I can't access the `client` inside `finally`. Is there a good pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use async/await:

```js
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
const db = client.db(dbName);
const dogs = db.collection('dogs');
...
```

When you have operations like find you can `await` them or using then as you did. If you are not very confident with promises, `asyn/await` might be clearer for you.
You can also await chained promises with then...

With async/await you can use try/catch/finally, that might be an easier solution for you.

Comment: Remember not to tell to your girlfriend that you are not confident with promises. She would never understand....

Comment: Why am I abusing of then? Am I using it too much?

Comment: My sentence was out of topic so I did delete it. It's all about structuring code in a different way to avoid that. Your example is ok, it was clear what you wanted to achieve so my sentence was not needed. Keep using async/await to flatten your code in the case above, that is the cleanest way to do it. Without changing the structure of your code you can easily delete at least the second `then` but as I said my then sentence was just entropy in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code with an async function in order to use await, and create a variable before the try and catch to save the client, the code will be as follows:

```js
const functionName = async () => {
  let client;
  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection("dogs");
    const array = collection.find().toArray();
    console.log(array);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
};
```